# Confusion about function composition in Haskell

Tags: haskell, function-composition, pointfree

Consider following function definition in ghci.

```
let myF = sin . cos . sum
```

where, . stands for composition of two function (right associative). This I can call

```
myF [3.14, 3.14]
```

and it gives me desired result. Apparently, it passes list [3.14, 3.14] to function 'sum' and its 'result' is passed to cos and so on and on. However, if I do this in interpreter

```
let myF y = sin . cos . sum y
```

or

```
let myF y = sin . cos (sum y)
```

then I run into troubles. Modifying this into following gives me desired result.

```
let myF y = sin . cos $ sum y
```

or

```
let myF y = sin . cos . sum $ y
```

The type of (.) suggests that there should not be a problem with following form since 'sum y' is also a function (isn't it? After-all everything is a function in Haskell?)

```
let myF y = sin . cos . sum y -- this should work?
```

What is more interesting that I can make it work with two (or many) arguments (think of passing list [3.14, 3.14] as two arguments x and y), I have to write the following

```
let (myF x) y = (sin . cos . (+ x)) y 
myF 3.14 3.14 -- it works! 
let myF = sin . cos . (+) 
myF 3.14 3.14 -- -- Doesn't work!
```

There is some discussion on HaskellWiki regarding this form which they call 'PointFree' form http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree . By reading this article, I am suspecting that this form is different from composition of two lambda expressions. I am getting confused when I try to draw a line separating both of these styles.

Comment: It is not true that "everything is a function in Haskell."  Conal Elliot has [a great discussion of this on his blog](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at the [types](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/). For `sin` and `cos` we have:

```
cos, sin :: Floating a => a -> a
```

For `sum`:

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

Now, `sum y` turns that into a

```
sum y :: Num a => a
```

which is a value, not a function (you could name it a function with no arguments but this is very tricky and you also need to name `() -> a` functions - <del>there was a discussion somewhere about this but I cannot find the link now</del> - [Conal](http://conal.net/blog/posts/everything-is-a-function-in-haskell) spoke about it).

Anyway, trying `cos . sum y` won't work because `.` expects both sides to have types `a -> b` and `b -> c` (signature is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`) and `sum y` cannot be written in this style. That's why you need to include parentheses or `$`.

As for point-free style, the simples translation recipe is this:

- take you function and move the last argument of function to the end of the expression separated by a function application. For example, in case of `mysum x y = x + y` we have `y` at the end but we cannot remove it right now. Instead, rewriting as `mysum x y = (x +) y` it works.
- remove said argument. In our case `mysum x = (x +)`
- repeat until you have no more arguments. Here `mysum = (+)`

(I chose a simple example, for more convoluted cases you'll have to use `flip` and others)

Comment: Hi Mihai. Thanks for this. If you can locate the link, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What might help make this even clearer is looking at the type of `.`, which is `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)`.

Comment: Updated with the link and the signature for `.` as @Antal S-Z suggested

Answer (score 7):

No, `sum y` is not a function. It's a number, just like `sum [1, 2, 3]` is. It therefore makes complete sense that you cannot use the function composition operator `(.)` with it.

Not everything in Haskell are functions.

Comment: I thought numbers were functions with void argument.

Comment: @eternalmatt: Read the blog post Antal S-Z linked to in the comments above.

Answer (score 4):

The obligatory cryptic answer is this:  (space) binds more tightly than `.`

Most whitespace in Haskell can be thought of as a very high-fixity `$` (the "apply" function). `w x . y z` is basically the same as `(w $ x) . (y $ z)`

When you are first learning about `$` and `.` you should also make sure you learn about  (space) as well, and make sure you understand how the language semantics implicitly parenthesize things in ways that may not (at first blush) appear intuitive.